# Make an annotation in ggplot with applying styles on the certain symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, italics

I am trying to put the r2 value and p-value in the same annotation in a graph.

The r and the p needs to be italicized with a comma in between the two values so `r^2 = 0.26, p = 0.005`.

I have looked up suggestions but I can't get everything I want. The first example code gets me everything but the italic p.

I have tried putting paste italic in front of it like I did with the r but it gives me an error and the second script the r and the p are italic but I can't figure out how to put a comma in between them

```
annotate("text", x=93, y=65, 
         label= "paste(italic(r)^{2}, \" = 0.26, \",p, \" = 0.0008\")", 
         parse=TRUE, size=4)
```

---

```
annotate("text", x=93, y=65, 
         label= "italic(r)^{2}==0.26~italic(p)==0.0008", 
         parse=TRUE, size=4)
```

I want the r and the p to be italic and I want a comma between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot()+
  annotate("text", x=93, y=65, 
           label= "paste(italic(r)^{2}, \" = 0.26, \",italic(p), \" = 0.0008\")", 
           parse=TRUE, size=4) + 
  #setting axis to blank just to make this visually appealing:
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]